# Why are components of my custom control not initiated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, custom-controls

I'm making a `GenericTable` as a custom implementation of `GridView` that will display the values of any list of objects that's inserted.

To use the control on an aspx page it needs to be a UserControl, so the `GridView` is included as a component in the `GenericTable`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GenericTable.ascx.cs" Inherits="CASH.WebApplication.Controls.GenericTable" %>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll">
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

This works fine for the first use of my control, it's added on the aspx page. It seems that doing that adds some sort of magic that initiates the control components.
When the user clicks on an item that has properties of it's own, the `GenericTable` should insert a row below the current row and spawn a new `GenericTable` that will show said properties. `table` is the DataTable that I use to set the `GridView` contents:

```
var data = table.NewRow();
var child = new GenericTable();

data[0] = child;

table.Rows.InsertAt(data, row);
grid.DataSource = table;
grid.DataBind(); // The extra row is displayed now, initialize components in the aspx code?
child.MakeTable(); // Throws exception because it's `grid` property is null.
```

When I try to activate the newly made `GenericTable`, after this code, it's `grid` is null.

Is there a way to initialize the same magic that happens when this control is located in the aspx code?

Update: Maybe the problem lies in how the table is stored between postbacks, currently I'm using the session, maybe there's a better way to remember user input?
The whole `GenericTable` code:

```
using Project.DomainModel.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CASH.WebApplication.Controls
{
    public partial class GenericTable : UserControl
    {
        private PropertyInfo[] properties;
        //private GridView gridView;
        private DataTable table = new DataTable();
        private Dictionary<int, int> ingedrukt = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grid.RowCommand += WeergaveDossiers_RowCommand;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    grid.Rows[i].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                properties = (PropertyInfo[])Session["properties"];
                table = (DataTable)Session["table"];
                ingedrukt = (Dictionary<int, int>)Session["ingedrukt"];

                foreach (var knop in ingedrukt)
                {
                    DetailRijToevoegen(knop.Key, knop.Value);
                }
            }

            grid.DataBind();
        }

        protected void SaveInSession()
        {
            Session["properties"] = properties;
            Session["table"] = table;
            Session["ingedrukt"] = ingedrukt;
        }

        protected void WeergaveDossiers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int row = int.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument) + 1;
            int col = GetKolomIndex(e.CommandName) + 1;

            if (ingedrukt.ContainsKey(row))
            {
                if (ingedrukt[row] != col)
                {
                    //DetailRijVerwijderen(row);
                    //ingedrukt.Remove(row);
                    //ingedrukt[row] = col;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ingedrukt[row] = col;
            }

            //DetailRijToevoegen(row, col);
            SaveInSession();
        }

        protected void DetailRijToevoegen(int row, int col)
        {
            var data = table.NewRow();
            var child = new GenericTable();
            child.grid = new GridView();

            data[0] = child;

            table.Rows.InsertAt(data, row);
            grid.DataSource = table;
            grid.DataBind();

            var cells = grid.Rows[row].Cells;
            // Only keep the first cell
            while (cells.Count > 1)
            {
                cells.RemoveAt(1);
            }

            child.MaakTable(new List<object>() { table.Rows[row][col] });

            grid.Columns[0].Visible = true;
            grid.Rows[row].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = table.Columns.Count;
        }

        protected void DetailRijVerwijderen(int row)
        {

        }

        protected int GetKolomIndex(string naam)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                if (properties[i].Name == naam)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            throw new InvalidDataException("Kolom naam " + naam + " niet bekend");
        }

        public void MaakTable(IEnumerable<object> data)
        {
            properties = data.First().GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead).ToArray();

            grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            var details = new BoundField();
            details.DataField = "Details";
            grid.Columns.Add(details);

            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Details", typeof(object)));
            foreach (var veld in properties)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(veld.Name, (veld.Name == "Id" ? typeof(object) : veld.PropertyType)));
                grid.Columns.Add(MaakKolom(veld));
            }

            foreach (var entry in data)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();
                int col = 0;

                foreach (var veld in properties)
                {
                    row[++col] = veld.GetValue(entry);
                }

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            grid.DataSource = table;

            SaveInSession();
        }

        protected DataControlField MaakKolom(PropertyInfo veld)
        {
            DataControlField field;

            if (typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(veld.PropertyType))
            {
                field = new ButtonField();
                ((ButtonField)field).DataTextField = veld.Name;
                ((ButtonField)field).ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
                ((ButtonField)field).CommandName = veld.Name;
            }
            else if (veld.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            {
                field = new CheckBoxField();
                ((CheckBoxField)field).DataField = veld.Name;
            }
            else if (veld.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                field = new TemplateField();
                //((TemplateField)field).ItemTemplate = (ITemplate)new Label()
                //{
                //  Text = "#DataBinder.Eval(\"" + veld.Name + "\")",
                //};
            }
            else if (veld.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                field = new TemplateField();
                //field.DatePicker = true;
            }
            else
            {
                field = new BoundField();
                ((BoundField)field).DataField = veld.Name;
            }

            field.HeaderText = veld.Name;

            return field;
        }

        protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your custom control. Also can you explain what you are trying to do in your second piece of code?

Comment: I would avoid using Session for storing page instance specific data to be persisted across postbacks.  It can add memory pressure on your web server (especially when storing large items like datatables), and also will have conflicts if you open 2 tabs with the same webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to acheive, I just know that what you're doing is fundamentally wrong (well, in terms of the ASP.NET view of the world...).

1. You're adding your control to the input *data*, rather than adding it as a *sub-control* of the grid.
2. You're not instantiating the GridView control in the consructor of your control.
3. `Session` is *absolutely* the wrong place to store lots of page-related data.

I'll start with the last point first: If this is data that needs to persist between visits to the site, then you *must* put it into a database. If this is data that only exists from the time someone logs in, to the time they logout, then yes, `Session` *may* be the right place for it. Otherwise, if it's specific to the page and should be discarded when the user visits a different one, then you should either reload it from the database every time or *maybe* store it in the `ViewState`.

Next, are all the objects of the same type / do they have the same fields? If so, then the default behaviour (controlled explicitly by `AutoGenerateColumns` will do the job for you, no extra work required:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server"
    ID="grid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

If the do *not* have the same columns, then they should be in *seperate* grids; a `GridView` is a way of creating an HTTP `<table>` element. A table element should only contain *related* data; you wouldn't use a single table for displaying prices of fish and colours of cars. It follows from this, that if you have different tables, with unrelated data, then you should have different data sources... a more simple solution that means you don't *need* to implement the control you're trying to implement.

Finally, for completeness, when you define a control, you're just creating a class. If you want to be able to instantiate a control in the way you are trying, then you need to make sure that all its data members are a instantiated in the constructor *or* that any references are guarded by null-reference checks:

```
if (grid != null)
{
    // Do stuff with grid
}
```

Comment: The data should not be persisted between visits, it's just to remember what items the user opened. So if I understand you correctly my custom control should be a table with GridViews or other tables that contain GridViews elements, but not GridViews inside GridViews.

Comment: More like a list of tables... `<asp:Panel><asp:GridView ID="grid1"/><asp:GridView ID="grid2" /></asp:Panel>` or `Panel panel; var grid1=new GridView(); var grid2=new GridView(); panel.AddControl(grid1); panel.AddControl(grid2);`

Comment: Also, if your data is _not_ related (it's got different columns) maybe you should just use a seperate page for it; keep it simple to begin with and re-work/combine pages as your knowledge and confidence grows - that's how I started out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Static datatable option and update the datatable first and rebind it to the grid without loosing data.

Comment: I need a different `DataTable` per instance, so can't make it static. The problem is that my `grid` is null, so I can't do anything with it.

Comment: Creating the datasource during runtime actually creates problem. How about using SQL table and refreshing the grid after adding it. Not sure but that could be the option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need to achieve can simply be achieved by creating a class inheriting from the grid view. That way you will get all the features for Grid View and your additional properties without worrying about the implementation details for custom control.

If you still think you need to create a custom control then, post the code for your custom control that will help understand the issue.

If you do not wish to post the code for some reason then [visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413799/extending-asp-net-textbox-and-adding-a-hidden-field/21414363#21414363) where I answered a question related custom control only. I think you would be able to find a solution to your problem there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this first, it din't work because I was unable to add it to the ToolBox because it was not a `UserControl`. Adding it to the page with code caused the DataBind to fail.

Comment: If you post the code for custom control it would be easy to identify the problem, I am pretty sure the issue lies in there only.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a link, I think you will get a solution there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing how your gridview "grid" is connected to your "child" custom control. It won't have the grid property if your don't have them linked together?

You could be doing this behind the scenes in something in your custom control but that definately needs to be done.

My logic goes: Something you think is defined is null. Did you define it?

Comment: This should happen by including the `GridView` on the aspx of the child and the runat="server" attribute on the `GridView`. It works on the first `GenericTable` control.

Comment: OK, hmmm. If I understand you correctly the grid is a property of the generic table on your page. I still think it could be a linking problem so maybe your new instance of the generic table "child" isn't connected to the instance in your aspx? i.e. child is not the thing on the page its something you just made so it doesn't have a grid?

Also you could try to edit your MakeTable() and handle the exception of a null grid and then look at what properties it has to give a clue?

Comment: Then my top level custom control disappears from the page. Probably because something when wrong when it was created so it was left out completely. If I make a new GridView for the childs grid property, the same.